# How to install "Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller" without internet connection on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, internet, ethernet, atheros

I was finally able to get the OS installed on my MSI Ghost Pro laptop (currently the only OS on the machine) only to discover that NONE of my networking drivers were working. `ifconfig` only shows the `lo` interface and nothing more. All of the troubleshooting guides I can find assume at least some method of being able to connect to the internet in order to make any fixes.

I know this question can be dependent on the specific drivers themselves, and was hoping someone could tell me if there is a way to get this particular ethernet driver working on Ubuntu 14.04, or any any other way of connecting this machine to the internet in order to make the necessary updates.

The particular Ethernet card on the machine is the 1969 ("Qualcomm Atheros"), device: e0a1 ("Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller")

Comment: If you are able to install Ubuntu 16.04 or later, the device is covered by the driver *alx* by default.

Answer (score 0):

According to [chili555's comment](/questions/843352/how-to-install-killer-e2400-gigabit-ethernet-controller-without-internet-conne#comment1292237_843352) that device is supported by the kernel shipped with Ubuntu 16.04. Luckily one can upgrade to the same kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 via LTS/HWE upgrades:

1. Install the kernel packages:

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-generic-lts-xenial
   ```
2. Reboot the machine. The newly installed kernel should be the new default boot option for Grub.

More info: [Ubuntu Wiki – LTS Enablement Stack](//wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_-_Trusty_Tahr)